# virtualenvwrapper: when does `workon` changes to the project directory?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, virtual-environment

I use [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/) to manage my environments. I create my projects with the `-a <path-to-project>` argument and `PROJECT_HOME` is not set, because my projects don't share a common path. `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_WORKON_CD` is set to `1` though and a valid `.project` file exist in the virtual environments.

When I use the `workon` command, it only changes the working directory to the path of the project *sometimes*, while at other times, the directory stays the same, despite the environment being activated correctly.

**So when and how does the directory change trough `workon` happens? And are there things I have to do / set for it to work?**

Comment: Have you tried running the command

    setvirtualenvproject

in the directory that you want to cd into after you have activated the project?

Comment: Yes, tried that. And also verified, that the `.project` files contain the correct path.

Comment: This happens after I close my terminal and reopen it again. It seems virtualenvwrapper is not saving the configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a small solution albeit kinda hacky

1. Go to the folder which this variable, `$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR` is pointing to. You might need to be in a virtual environment to see that variable, but usually it has the same value as `$WORKON_HOME`
2. In this folder you should see a script called `postactivate`
3. Add this as the last line in the script: `cdproject`

Now what this does is that every time you type `workon <project_name>`, this script will run after the virtual environment is activated, and the directory you were working in will switch to the directory for that project.

**For more life-cycle hooks, see [here](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts.html)!**

**NOTE**

*I didn't fully test this to make sure it works no matter how the project was created, but to make sure it works, I recommend creating your virtual environments with `mkvirtualenv -a <env_name>` or if the environment exists and with the environment activated, go to it's project folder and run `setvirtualenvproject`.* Now the next time you try to do `workon ...`, the script will kick in and take you to your project folder

#### Addendum

Since this is a shell script, you can do some fancy tweaks than just that one line. For example you might want to only do something if the activated project has a certain pattern, or part of a certain group of projects. Checkout some of the `$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_*` variables to see what other useful information you can get

Comment: This worked. What I don't get, though, is why it sometimes did this automatically, without me ever setting a hook? Don't see the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

setvirtualenvproject is now called `setprojectdir`. To use the current directory write `setprojectdir .`

Comment: Not in my version of virtualenvwrapper ($ pip show virtualenvwrapper
Name: virtualenvwrapper
Version: 4.8.4)